# Android - Correct way to move layouts/ImageViews

Tags: android, android-layout

first of all apologize for my English. I'm starting to develop games using android and I've done one like a test for a friends wedding (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vicgames.polaravalanche).

Testing it on different devices, what I see is that:

- In the Samsung Galaxy and Neo N003 (I guess it happens with more devices, no matter the version of android), when sharks are launched from the tornado, they are not visibles (but they hit the player)
- The Nexus 5 (with which I have done most of the testing) works as I want.
- For other devices, launching sharks usually go faster than Nexus 5 but works well

Take the example with the launching sharks, but basically the question is focused in general to move any layout / Imageview.

I put a sample code as I have done, although I've tried different ways:

- tiburon.animate().translationX(x).translationY(y).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).setDuration(velocidadTiburon)
- Final ObjectAnimator animX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat (shark, "translationX", x);
- Also with the same ObjectAnimator but with "x" instead of translationX and Y.
- I also tried with TranslateAnimation with calculated values ​​or relative.
- I also tried with layoutParams.leftMargin.
- I also tried directly setX and setY.

But I think that is not the correct way, because depending on if I use one or the other, It do not work equally on all devices. Maybe the problem is not the way as I do, maybe is how I calculate the positions (pixels, dps), but again I tried different ways, but still varies between devices.

Maybe I have no need to move the layouts / imagevies directly like the backgrounds in this game, with a synchronized (surfaceHolder) and painting in the canvas. But I wonder you have to do so, because for something so simple, I think if they move directly layout / Imageview, should be the same for any device.

I also wonder if the problem will be for the duration of the movements/animations, maybe I  need to put it differently depending on the size of the device.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my question, because I have found the cause. When I had rooted the phone, I had modified some development options in the Nexus 5, to make it all "faster". I had changed the options from 1x to 1.5x, so the performance was different:

- Windows animation scale.
- Transition animation scale.
- Animator duration scale.

Kind regards.

Comment: That doesn't need root it's in developer options.On my device at least